# Apache Atlas - Hive bridge not triggerd with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-atlas

When submiting spark job using Hive,
The Spark job save / override table in hive using command
`df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database.tableName")`

Apache Atlas don't see trigger of Hive that has new data

How to force Apache Atlas see table creation / modification from spark

Comment: Spark is **not** using Hive to read/write data files. It has its own query optimizer and I/O libraries. The only actions that could "trigger" anything are table or partition creation in the Metastore.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter using Hive in Spark lib. eg SparkQL will trigger ?

Comment: Repeating: SparQL **never** uses Hive to read/write data. It **may** use the Hive Metastore, if correctly configured. But the Metastore does not care about data files. It cares about tables, partitions, schema - and the directories where data files are stored.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, you said `The only actions that could "trigger" anything are table or partition creation in the Metastore` and then you said `It may use the Hive Metastore` - might be, that usage of `sparkql` that updates hive metadata it should trigger Atlas events (via http://atlas.apache.org/0.6.0-incubating/Bridge-Hive.html)?

Comment: I don't know much about Atlas. But "INSERT" or "TRUNCATE" or "INSERT OVERWRITE" have no effect on the Metastore.